# Ruby while loop with math

Tags: ruby

I am working on a lab for class about 'while' loops. This is the goal:

> - Create a variable and set it equal to true
> - While the variable you just created is true
> - Prompt user for number
> - Read in number
> - Compute double that number
> - Display double that number
> - Prompt the user if they want to go again
> - Read in that text
> - If that text input is “n” then set the true variable to false

This is the code I have:

```
puts "Enter a number"
x = Float(gets.chomp())

product = x * 2
puts "Double your number is"
puts product

while
  puts "Go again   y/n?"
  answer = gets.chomp
  if answer != 'y'
  end
end
```

The directions seem clear, but I don't understand how to turn it into code.

Any modifications will help.

Comment: Hint #1: "Create a variable and set it equal to true."

Comment: Hint #2: "While the variable is true". See [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_loops.htm) on how to properly write a while loop.

Comment: Hint #3: Everything that is supposed to happen "while the variable is true" needs to go *inside* the while loop.

Comment: Hint #4: "If that text input is “n” then set the true variable to false." The 'true variable' will be the variable you set in Hint #1. (Bonus points for doing this step without using an `if` statement! You're actually pretty close.)

Comment: Note that in Ruby the style is generally `x = gets.chomp.to_f` where empty argument lists are omitted and force-casting with things like `Float()` is strongly discouraged.

Comment: @tadman _"force-casting with things like Float() is strongly discouraged"_ – could you elaborate, please? When would `Float()` be the right or better choice?

Comment: @Stefan In C++, PHP and others you'd write `(float) x` where that converts `x` to a `float`. Naturally some people think that the equivalent in Ruby would be `Float(x)`, since as far as syntax goes thats' the closest, but it's actually `x.to_f` due to the principle of [Duck Typing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing). In other words, any object that can handle a `.to_f` call is an acceptable value, not necessarily one that plays nice with `Float`.

Comment: @tadman thank's for clarifying. I've never thought of it that way but you are right, `(float) x` is very close to `Float(x)` syntax-wise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have a boolean flag to check at while level each loop:

```
again = true

while again
  puts "Enter a number "
  x = Float(gets.chomp())

  product = x * 2
  puts "Double your number is"
  puts product 

  puts "Go again y/n? "

  again = gets.chomp != 'n'
end
```

Comment: Could always `loop do ... end` and then `break if answer.downcase == 'y'`

Comment: True. But the requirement asks for a Boolean var.

Comment: `if answer == 'n'` would match the requirements more closely.

Comment: Could do `again = answer == 'n'` if that's the case, no need for the `if` in that case. This is an XY problem, so don't be afraid to get to the root of the issue.

Comment: @tadman, nice tip! Updated. PS: it should check for `!= 'n'` to loop again.

Comment: @Robert Indeed. Good that someone's paying attention to the details!

Comment: The instructions don't say that the answer has to be stored in a variable, so you could inline that variable, i.e. `again = gets.chomp != 'n'`